# IE 10 and link as a block - can't get this to work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I have a web site (http://www.interactstaging.net/clients/tozzi/) with drop down menus which works perfectly under Firefox and Chrome but not IE10.

An example HTML code for menu part looks like:

```
<div class="navi"><a href="http://www.interactstaging.net/clients/tozzi/"><em class="hover"></em><span>Home</span></a></div>
```

and CSS for that part:

```
.navi a span {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 0 7px;
line-height: 28px;
z-index: 100; 
height: 45px; }
```

Any clue why that CSS is not working under IE10?

Thanks

Comment: You can't nest block elements inside inline elements.  In your case I think the `<a>` element is inline and you are trying to make the `<span>` it contains block-level.  --  just a guess

Comment: Well based on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881620/problem-with-ie-when-using-displayblock-for-links it is correct

Comment: a elent in this case is block see .sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

Comment: .sf-menu a is related to the submenus not top menu - take a look now when height was added to the .sf-menu - still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS rule:

```
.sf-menu li {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That is interesting. Never heard that block should to have filled background to do not count as a transparent. It looks like an old times with transparent GIFs and tables. Thanks for that tip!